# Finding element by ID is not working in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

When I use the find element by ID it is not working in my code.

--This is the HTML where the 4 tabs appears. Under each option there is nav option which has the id. Each of the 4 tabs also has ids. But identifying using those are not working.

HTML:

```
<nav id="monitoring-tab" class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal ng-scope">
  <ul>
    <li id="now-tab" ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" ng-hide="hideTab.now" class="ng-hide">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.real-time" href="#/monitoring/real-time">
        Now</a>
    </li>
    <li id="day-tab" ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" class="pure-menu-selected">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day" href="#/monitoring/historical/day">
        Day</a>
    </li>
    <li id="month-tab" ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.month" href="#/monitoring/historical/month">
        Month</a>
    </li>
    <li id="year-tab" ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.year" href="#/monitoring/historical/year">
        Year</a>
    </li>
    <li id="lifetime-tab" ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.lifetime" href="#/monitoring/historical/lifetime">
        Lifetime</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="date-range" ng-hide="stateName =='app.monitoring.historical.lifetime'" class="ng-scope">
  <span>
    <a id="historical-nav-prev" ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day({date:'2014-10-16'})" href="#/monitoring/historical/day?date=2014-10-16">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="ng-binding">Fri, Oct 17, 2014</span>
  <span ng-show="historicalNav.nextDateBtnShown" class="ng-hide">
    <a id="historical-nav-next" ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day({date:''})" href="#/monitoring/historical/day?date=">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

MyCode:

```
it('Should click on the previous day', function() {

    element(by.id('historical-nav-prev')).click();
    });
```

Error:

```
   NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("historical-nav-p
rev")
```

What is wrong here? Most of the id's I am using are not working.

Comment: Does `$('#historical-nav-prev').click();` work?

Comment: No didn't work.I edited my html to include more code.Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure the page is loading and the element is clickable?  You may need to wait for the element before you try to click it.

Comment: @LeoGallucci. - No. It is not.@user2272115 - I tried that one also :(.